# SharePoint 2016 Checkin using C# - FileNotFound Exception

Tags: c#, sharepoint, automation, sharepoint-2016

I am using the below code to check-in a file to SharePoint 2016 using C#. But it is throwing *Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException: File Not Found.* The file URL is valid and file.name is printed in the console confirming its validity. Please advise what is going wrong here.

```
            string url = "valid url of the file";
            var file = clientContext.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(url);
            clientContext.Load(file);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            Console.WriteLine(file.Name); //successfully printed expected result
            file.CheckIn("Test", CheckinType.MajorCheckIn);
            clientContext.Load(file);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery(); //File Not Found Exception thrown at this point
```

Comment: why loading the file twice in context?

Comment: Even after I removed loading, it's not working and throwing the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
using (ClientContext clientContext = GetContextObject())
{
    string url = "valid url of the file";
    var file = clientContext.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(url);

    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open))
    {
        File.SaveBinaryDirect(clientContext, file, fs, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not throwing exception and saving the file. But, still the file is not checked-in.That's the ultimate objective and it's not happening :(

Answer (score 0):

You might find that the "valid url of the file" is not actually valid. I am getting this error from a URL that is "valid" in the sense that opens the file in Sharepoint from the browser but I think the filename has some characters that the C# CSOM interface doesn't support. In my case the file is called "GetPDF.aspx%2F4AA3-8247ENW.pdf", so it's probably because it has two periods, but I'm struggling to confirm that.

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at https://www.codesharepoint.com/csom/get-checkin-comment-of-file-in-sharepoint-using-csom. I've never used CSOM and GetFileByServerRelativeUrl, but I seem to recall CheckIn has to occur on the file as opposed to the item containing the file.